# How to convert SolrNet Get Method to Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, solrnet

We have a working Web API endpoint that does a search with SolrNet.

To receive the Solr core name via querystring, instead of hard coding in Startup method we switched to the Windsor configuration.

How do I write the following using the Windsor method?

**Current Working Code:**

```
            // Application_Start()
            var connection = new SolrConnection("url/");
            var loggingConnection = new LoggingConnection(connection);
            Startup.Init<product>(loggingConnection);

            // GET api/query
            var conn = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrConnection>();             
            var xml = conn.Get("/select", query);
```

**We tried the following, but resolve doesn't work with ISolrConnection:**

```
            // GET api/core/query/
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            var solrFacility = new SolrNetFacility("url/" + core);
            container.AddFacility("solr", solrFacility);                

            var conn = container.Resolve<ISolrConnection<product>>();             
            var xml = conn.Get("/select", query);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Exception? If so, what's the exception?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  It wouldn't compile with the error "cannot be used with type argument".  It didn't click to me at first, but now I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

ISolrConnection can't be type product.

The solution was as follows:

```
        // GET api/core/query/
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        var solrFacility = new SolrNetFacility("url/" + core);
        container.AddFacility("solr", solrFacility);                

        var conn = container.Resolve<ISolrConnection>();             
        var xml = conn.Get("/select", query);
```